# What is the error in it and it is very simple, error is showing in the last 'end' statement. What is the error

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, triggers, case

There is an error in this code. How can I find it out?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `check` BEFORE INSERT ON `whatstore` FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    declare last_insert_time datetime;
    declare new_insert_time datetime;
    set @last_insert_time=(select insert_time from whatstore order by id desc limit 1);
    select datediff(new.insert_time,@last_inserted_time) into new_insert_time;
    case 
        when last_insert_time-new.insert_time>1 then insert into `delete`.table3(time_diff)  values(new_inserted_time);
    end
END
```

Comment: but the case need end statemant deleting it will give another error

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a [`CASE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html), not a `CASE` expression.

I would advise you to just use `IF`, but you can adjust your code with `END CASE`:

```
 begin
    declare last_insert_time datetime;
    declare new_insert_time datetime;

    set @last_insert_time = (select insert_time from whatstore order by id desc limit 1);

    select datediff(new.insert_time, @last_inserted_time) into new_insert_time;

    case when last_insert_time - new.insert_time > 1 
         then insert into `delete`.table3 (time_diff)  
                  values (new_inserted_time);
    end case;
end;
```

It seems simpler to write this with no conditional logic:

```
insert into `delete`.table3 (time_diff)  
    select w.last_insert_time
    from (select insert_time
          from whatstore 
          order by id desc
          limit 1
         ) w
    where w.last_insert_time > new.insert_time;
```